# Phonegap with PHP as a server side?

Tags: php, node.js, cordova

I have a quick question. I want to develop a cross platform app using phonegap.. is it possible to use PHP as a server side script? because I've seen many articles say that if you want to use the phonegap.. you have to use node js as a server side script.. any idea?

Comment: I think you are confused, phonegap uses node for the CLI, but on the server you can use any programming language

Comment: good question @Riad, this is what i was looking for and as this question is pretty old from you could you please tell did you carried out your plan and what language you end up using at the back end ?

Comment: I ended up using PHP.. The project was for testing purposes .. SPA, Promises, Angular, and Ionic.. I have been leaning Node.js so I can use it efficiently with Angular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [PhoneGap FAQs](http://phonegap.com/about/faq/):

> A PhoneGap application may only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. However, you can make use of network protocols (XmlHTTPRequest, Web Sockets, etc) to easily communicate with backend services written in any language.

So yes, you can use PHP as server side language and communicate from phonegap with ajax. Example: http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/updated-loading-data-in-phonegap-using-jquery-1-5/